# Embedded Jetty doesn't serve webapp from resources

Tags: java, web-applications, jetty, war, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to serve webapp packed as war from jar resources. It does not run, just show the list of files in webapp folder.

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
WebAppContext webapp = new WebAppContext();
webapp.setContextPath("/app");
webapp.setWar(this.getClass().getResource("/webapp/app-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war").toExternalForm());
webapp.setExtractWAR(true);
server.setHandler(webapp);
server.start();
server.join();
```

Output:

```
java -jar target/embedded-jetty-1-SNAPSHOT.jar 
2018-02-28 12:35:08.535:INFO::main: Logging initialized @86ms
2018-02-28 12:35:08.582:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.3.z-SNAPSHOT
2018-02-28 12:35:10.645:INFO:oejw.StandardDescriptorProcessor:main: NO 
JSP Support for /app, did not find 
org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet
2018-02-28 12:35:10.657:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started 
o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@326de728{/app,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-app-
1.0-SNAPSHOT.war-_app-any-492743292110960435.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}
{jar:file:/home/user/embedded-jetty/target/embedded-jetty-1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/webapp/app-1.0-
SNAPSHOT.war}
2018-02-28 12:35:10.664:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started 
ServerConnector@6ad5c04e{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2018-02-28 12:35:10.665:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @2217ms
```

[Result in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kE4Mx.png)

Comment: Please post the output that you are getting currently.

Comment: @SandeepRandhawa updated

Comment: That would mean you have triple-compressed content in the main jar. (`jar` -> `war` -> `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar`).   Consider at least unpacking the war into your jar, and unpacking the `WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` files into different location in your jar.

Comment: Or just use a live-war format instead.  https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-live-war

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt how should look directories structure and how to configure Jetty to serve this app using libs from /resources/lib?

Comment: there's many different ways to organize that, i can think of a few dozen different ways myself.  since you are considering embedded-jetty, you might want to look at not using a war / WebAppContext, but the ServletContextHandler and manual declaration of servlets and filters to simplify things.